# How to load huge data in tablelayout

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am trying to load huge data which contains images and text and are fetch from server,in tablelayout.Can someone suggest me how I should do that.Because Loading all row at once may cause application to crash.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do , is to use a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) with custom adapter . for more information read this [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) it will help you , now when you face other issue create these stuff post a new question

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I am trying to implement it as it gets done in iPhone.In iPhone you can load image when scrolling ends.There is specific function which triggered when scrolling end and in that function we can get visible rows in table and then load those row data only.Is there any such function in android.

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless look at this Adapter it will give the endless Adapter behavior

Answer (score 1):

Bestet is the ListView with custom adapter.

You can read more about [ListView and ListViewActivity](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and [custom adapter for listview](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20custom%20listview)

Comment: Thanks for reply.But can you tell me is there any function which gets triggered when scrolling ends.Can I get which row numbers of table are visible as in iPhone.

Comment: Yes you can implement Scroll listener.

Comment: How can I get visible row numbers when scrolling ends?